# Pandas split corresponding rows based on separator in two columns duplicating everything else

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have an excel sheet

```
Col1    Col2                          Col3            Col4
John    English\nMaths                34\n33          Pass
Sam     Science                       40              Pass
Jack    English\nHistory\nGeography   89\n07\n98      Pass
```

Need to convert it to

```
Col1    Col2      Col3    Col4
John    English   34      Pass
John    Maths     33      Pass
Sam     Science   40      Pass
Jack    English   89      Pass
Jack    History   07      Pass     
Jack    Geography 98      Pass
```

The excel sheet has `\n` as separator for corresponding Col2 and col3 column. Just need to pull each subject in a new row with its corresponding marks and copy all the other column contents as it is.

Tried

```
split_cols = ['Col2', 'Col3']

# loop over the columns and split them
separator = '\n'
for col in split_cols:
    df[[f'{col}_Split1', f'{col}_Split2']] = df[col].str.split(separator, n=1, expand=True).fillna('')

# create two new dataframes with the desired columns
df1 = df[['Col1', 'Col2_Split1', 'Col3_Split1', 'Col4']].rename(columns={'Col2_Split1': 'D', 'Col3_Split1': 'C'})
df2 = df[['Col1', 'Col2_Split2', 'Col3_Split2', 'Col4']].rename(columns={'Col2_Split2': 'D', 'Col3_Split2': 'C'})

# concatenate the two dataframes
final_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

# print the final dataframe
print(final_df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explode on multiple columns (with a recent version of Pandas >= 1.3) after exploding each string into list:

```
# First pass
out = (df.assign(Col2=df['Col2'].str.split('\n'), 
                 Col3=df['Col3'].str.split('\n')))

# Fix unbalanced lists
def pad(sr):
    n = max(sr.str.len())
    sr['Col2'] = np.pad(sr['Col2'], (0, n-len(sr['Col2'])))
    sr['Col3'] = np.pad(sr['Col3'], (0, n-len(sr['Col3'])))
    return sr

m = out['Col2'].str.len() != out['Col3'].str.len()
out.loc[m, ['Col2', 'Col3']] = out.loc[m, ['Col2', 'Col3']].apply(pad, axis=1)

# Second pass
out = out.explode(['Col2', 'Col3'], ignore_index=True)
print(out)

# Output
   Col1       Col2 Col3    Col4
0  John    English   34    Pass
1  John      Maths   33    Pass
2   Sam    Science   40    Pass
3  Jack    English   89    Pass
4  Jack    History   07    Pass
5  Jack  Geography   98    Pass
6  Ryan      Maths   12  Failed
7  Ryan    Science   10  Failed
8  Ryan    History    0  Failed
```

Input dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Col1': ['John', 'Sam', 'Jack', 'Ryan'],
        'Col2': ['English\nMaths', 'Science', 'English\nHistory\nGeography', 'Maths\nScience\nHistory'],
        'Col3': ['34\n33', '40', '89\n07\n98', '12\n10'],
        'Col4': ['Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Failed']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output
   Col1                         Col2        Col3    Col4
0  John               English\nMaths      34\n33    Pass
1   Sam                      Science          40    Pass
2  Jack  English\nHistory\nGeography  89\n07\n98    Pass
3  Ryan      Maths\nScience\nHistory      12\n10  Failed
```

Comment: ```ValueError: columns must have matching element counts```

Comment: You have unbalanced lists between Col2 and Col3. You have some rows where Col2 has more or less items of Col3. `A\nB\nC` <-> `1\n2` so C has no value.

Comment: Is there a way to handle such cases

Comment: Probably a slow way

Comment: Please Suggest, there shouldn't me much cases [expecting 1 or 2] where unbalanced lists would be encountered.

Comment: With unbalanced lists, you can modify the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74044665/18470692). For the last line, as suggested there in the comment underneath, you probably want to use: `result = df.drop(columns=columns).join(exploded)`

Comment: I updated my answer to take into account unbalanced lists. Can you check it please?

Comment: Yes the change worked, Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 1):

EDITED.

You can achieve your goals using `.str.split` + `.explode` methods.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([
  ["John", "English\nMaths", "34\n33", "Pass"],
  ["Sam", "Science", "40", "Pass"],
  ["Jack", "English\nHistory\nGeography", "89\n07\n98", "Pass"],
])

df[1] = df[1].str.split("\n")
df[2] = df[2].str.split("\n")
df = df.explode([1, 2])
print(df)
```

Comment: The issue is not related to NA values. The column values are separated with '\n' , i need to split those. Please check the edited question.

Comment: @spd Can you give the actual code + data that you used to create the example.